# calling google Url Shortner API in C#

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest, google-api

I want to call the [google url shortner API](http://code.google.com/apis/urlshortener/v1/getting_started.html) from my C# Console Application, the request I try to implement is:

> POST https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url
>
> Content-Type: application/json
>
> {"longUrl": "http://www.google.com/"}

When I try to use this code:

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.IO;
```

and the main method is:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string s = "http://www.google.com/";
    var client = new HttpClient();

    // Create the HttpContent for the form to be posted.
    var requestContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[] {new KeyValuePair<string, string>("longUrl", s),});

    // Get the response.            
    HttpResponseMessage response = client.Post("https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url",requestContent);

    // Get the response content.
    HttpContent responseContent = response.Content;

    // Get the stream of the content.
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseContent.ContentReadStream))
    {
        // Write the output.
        s = reader.ReadToEnd();
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
    Console.Read();
}
```

I get the error code 400: This API does not support parsing form-encoded input.
I don't know how to fix this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you can check the code below (made use of System.Net).
You should notice that the contenttype must be specfied, and must be "application/json"; and also the string to be send must be in json format.

```
using System;
using System.Net;

using System.IO;
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url");
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
            httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                string json = "{\"longUrl\":\"http://www.google.com/\"}";
                Console.WriteLine(json);
                streamWriter.Write(json);
            }

            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                var responseText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                Console.WriteLine(responseText);
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `const string MATCH_PATTERN = @"""id"": ?""(?<id>.+)"""; Console.WriteLine(Regex.Match(responseText, MATCH_PATTERN).Groups["id"].Value);` gets the shorten url.

Comment: application/json was the missing piece for me. Was using text/json, like an idiot.

Answer (score 3):

Google has a NuGet package for using the Urlshortener API.  Details can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/apis/urlshortener/v1).

Based on [this example](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client-samples/blob/master/UrlShortener.ShortenURL/Program.cs) you would implement it as such:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Urlshortener.v1;
using Google.Apis.Urlshortener.v1.Data;
using Google.Apis.Http;

namespace ConsoleTestBed
{
    class Program
    {
        private const string ApiKey = "YourAPIKey";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var initializer = new BaseClientService.Initializer
            {
                ApiKey = ApiKey,
                //HttpClientFactory = new ProxySupportedHttpClientFactory()
            };
            var service = new UrlshortenerService(initializer);
            var longUrl = "http://wwww.google.com/";
            var response = service.Url.Insert(new Url { LongUrl = longUrl }).Execute();

            Console.WriteLine($"Short URL: {response.Id}");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

If you are behind a firewall you may need to use a proxy.  Below is an implementation of the `ProxySupportedHttpClientFactory`, which is commented out in the sample above.  Credit for this goes to [this blog post](https://kzhendev.wordpress.com/2015/04/28/accessing-google-apis-through-a-proxy-with-net/).

```
class ProxySupportedHttpClientFactory : HttpClientFactory
{
    private static readonly Uri ProxyAddress 
        = new UriBuilder("http", "YourProxyIP", 80).Uri;
    private static readonly NetworkCredential ProxyCredentials 
        = new NetworkCredential("user", "password", "domain");

    protected override HttpMessageHandler CreateHandler(CreateHttpClientArgs args)
    {
        return new WebRequestHandler
        {
            UseProxy = true,
            UseCookies = false,
            Proxy = new WebProxy(ProxyAddress, false, null, ProxyCredentials)
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about changing

```
   var requestContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[] 
        {new KeyValuePair<string, string>("longUrl", s),});
```

to

```
   var requestContent = new StringContent("{\"longUrl\": \" + s + \"}");
```

Comment: it gives this error: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'string' to System.Net.Http.HttpContent'

Comment: Error: 'System.Net.Http.HttpContent' does not contain a definition for 'CreateEmpty'

Comment: Sorry, re-read the full question and realized I was answering it incorrectly. Please see the latest revision.

Answer (score 0):

Following is my working code. May be its helpful for you.

```
private const string key = "xxxxxInsertGoogleAPIKeyHerexxxxxxxxxx";
public string urlShorter(string url)
{
            string finalURL = "";
            string post = "{\"longUrl\": \"" + url + "\"}";
            string shortUrl = url;
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?key=" + key);
            try
            {
                request.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
                request.Method = "POST";
                request.ContentLength = post.Length;
                request.ContentType = "application/json";
                request.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
                using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    byte[] postBuffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(post);
                    requestStream.Write(postBuffer, 0, postBuffer.Length);
                }
                using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
                {
                    using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        using (StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                        {
                            string json = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
                            finalURL = Regex.Match(json, @"""id"": ?""(?.+)""").Groups["id"].Value;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // if Google's URL Shortener is down...
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
            }
            return finalURL;
}
```