# How to create a short URL having ticket details, user login id - password details and some user specific details

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, short-url

How I can create a short URL which will show my page or redirect to my page.
URL will have user session / ticket details so which will be useful to show user specific details.

I was thinking to create a table and save details in it with short URL and Long URL. when user entered short URL go to table fetch long URL and redirect user to Long URL.

I am using C# MVC .NET

Following my  current URL for opening my page having Ticket, Branch Details, User Id details.                                        mywebsite.com/ExternalUser/getData?branchName=Demo%20Branch&encryptedTicket=776B5831A322264FFCF0AC5436A62414287CCBE2F3BA49AA364DB2D356CFD386AF97749DCD122DA928E6264E72192A04C2722EBC9DCD33F55B931A8F7BF4E9A843192C9AE07682F368B22D9648F8AF5C8AE42D3C239C7DD04B7BE8C2DAC7202618856D91D7CEAEE511B4F1B43472F6CBAE4A6A3788CA112A84F9420EBD919EF059E935AE6BF2094CE8957833DD5FC733A434428D10A28FCCC658D7ED6E85A45A02AC8876262D3DC2B7C78F481866169855307C063FF88612C08E2A932251690C10A942893AACBA577710780B80AA8CE5&branchCode=demo&userid=demo123

I want to short url with all this content like mywebsite.com/5-6 char url

Comment: What url are you wanting? You can just define route definitions.

Comment: Better create a small ID kinda thing and send thru the small URL and just fetch the ID -> details to know all other details would be nicer idea.

Comment: can you show us your ticket entity Id? and what type is Branch Id?

Comment: I have mention in my question branchCode = demo userid=demo123 etc

Comment: You can use API shortner library. Example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8030026/calling-google-url-shortner-api-in-c-sharp)